# C++ string input breaking my int cin?

Tags: c++

So, I have something simple like...

```
int userinput = 0;

cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> userinput;

while (userinput != 1 && userinput != 2 ) { //etc for menu options
    cout << "Invalid entry! Try again! ";
    cin >> userinput;
}
```

And it works fine so long as I enter numbers, but if I enter 'a' it breaks my program and goes into an infinite loop... Which makes no sense, from what I understand of C++. Since I typed userinput as an int, wouldn't it take 'a' as the ASCII value for a and give an invalid input error for not being a number on my menu list? Why the infinite loop, and how do I stop it? I'm coding in Visual Studio 2012 if it makes any difference...

Comment: `wouldn't it ... give an invalid input error for not being a number` It does exactly that - but your code isn't checking errors. That infinite loop you observe is `cin >> userinput` reading the same character and failing to parse it, over and over.

Comment: There are probably a million duplicates for this.

Comment: The stream won't parse `'a'` in its ASCII equivalent since it is a character and not an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the stream

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

immediately after `cout<<...`, and `#include <limits>` at the beginning of the program.

As @Igor said, after you read a non-number, `cin` fails to parse it, and the loop repeats, and same thing happens again and again. That's why resetting the stream solves it, it "consumes" whatever was left unparsed in the stream.

Comment: Should be `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());`

Comment: Thanks guys... Still VERY new to C++, but I was trying to validate my input and was trying to think of weird inputs I could do, and successfully broke my program =P

Comment: @NeilKirk, absolutely, forgot to add, actually it has to be `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');` (otherwise ignores the rest of the stream, this way we can press ENTER for a new read). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have "userinput" as an integer value, and 'a' isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pass a character to this program you can just use cin for the character and pass it to integer afterwards. Or you can create a wrapper class for integer and overload the cin to accept either a character or an integer input for the class.